# Is it possible to calculate field of view and aperture given focal length, k1 and k2?

Tags: aperture, focal-length, field-of-view, distortion

I have some data coming from an API that looks like this:

`"camera_parameters": [0.785028, 0.032519, -0.053622]`

and the data structure that I would like to obtain should look something like this:

`{"fNumber": 2.2,"fLen": 4.15 ,"vFOV": 57.71602, "vZF": 189.0, "aperture": 2.200000047683716}`

Is it possible to calculate: field of view and aperture given: focal length, k1 and k2? (where k1 and k2 would be the first and the second radial distortion coefficients respectively)

Comment: Angle of view depends on focal length and sensor dimensions (field of view depends on angle of view and focus distance). Aperture is a physical property of the lens (specifically the usually adjustable iris, and even more specifically the virtual image of the iris from the front of the lens compared to the focal length). I don't know what the distortion coefficients would have to do with either of those...

Comment: @twalberg I am completely out of the loop. This is for a project. Thank you for at least clarifying that they have nothing to do with each other!